# ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "tp"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am unable to figure out what is wrong in my SQL query

my query

```
SELECT distinct tp.class, tp.country 
FROM classes as tp, (SELECT distinct battle 
                     FROM outcomes 
                     WHERE outcomes.ship in (SELECT ships.name 
                                             FROM ships 
                                             WHERE ships.class = tp.class)) as sq 
GROUP BY tp.class, tp.country;
```

gives an error

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "tp"  

LINE 1: ...(select ships.name from ships where ships.class = tp.class))...
                                                             ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "tp", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

I am using postgresql 12.
I saw other similar questions on stack overflow, but I am unable to figure out my error from the given solutions.

Comment: provide sample data and your desired output in table format

Comment: @Fahmi I have an excel sheet as input data. Is it ok if I share that whole sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a correlated subquery in the `from` clause.  This is allowed, but you need a lateral join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tp.class, tp.country 
FROM classes tp CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT DISTINCT o.battle 
      FROM outcomes o
      WHERE o.ship IN (SELECT s.name 
                       FROM ships s
                       WHERE s.class = tp.class
                      )
     ) as sq ;
```

There may be other ways to write the query, but this appears to be the apprach you are trying here.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a simple `join`

```
SELECT distinct tp.class, tp.country 
FROM classes as tp join ships on ships.class = tp.class
join outcomes on outcomes.ship=ships.name
```

Comment: I was not using join as I was not familiar with it. However this did solve my problem. I will learn more about join operation. Thanks

Comment: @Abhay Patil: Take an especially good look that you understand the DIFFERENCE between a LEFT-join and an INNER join.  A JOIN-statement without specifying left is an inner join. Also, there is the FULL join, but one almost never needs those.